# When to buy an Oracle?

Tags: league-of-legends

I've been going trough Q&A and haven't found a question like this. So basically, what I'm wondering about is - at what point of the game I should grab myself an Oracle? Whether I play as jungler or support, I like to have this very good item to help my team and make sure enemy team has to spend more money on wards.

Now, I know it's good to buy it if enemy team has lots of wards, especially in my teams jungle, but what if I've been dying too much? How to make a good decision when 400g won't be a waste? Because, if you buy Oracle and die 2 min later without clearing any wards... It's kinda waste of 400g!

Any tips & answers are appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buying oracles elixirs, like many other things, varies intensely by which champion you're playing!

In general, Carries should not purchase Oracle's elixers until they have most (if not all) of their core items. They squish much too easily to make it a worthwhile investment.

On the other hand, tanks and supports are the best candidates for "Oracle" duty. Supports make use of the elixir because they're expected to roam the map while placing their own wards. Any wards they find when placing their own is gold in their pockets and sinks their opponents'.

Tanks benefit from oracles because they have the survivability to protect the buff from fading with a careless death. Since tanks usually are also the initiators, Oracles allows them to keep the battlefield free from tactical stealth in response to their initiation (such as Akali Shroud or Talon Ult).

The circumstances change a little bit if you're playing against Shaco, Teemo or Twitch, as you'll want to trend towards more pink wards / oracles across the entire game. Without the advantage of their stealth and surprise, these champions will quickly fall to your team.

Comment: Very nice answer, thank you. So basically, if I'm playing, for example, Master Yi as jungler, I shouldn't really get an Oracle, since I can die in a matter of seconds, while on the other hand, if I'm playing a tanky jungler Udyr, Shyvana etc, getting an Oracle, considering I'd know how to protect it and not die right away, is the way to go.

Comment: @ms5keroid Yup, that sounds like a good plan to start! You'll get a better sense of it the more you play. :)

Comment: Right; they're too expensive to lose on a champ you expect to die more often. Also keep in mind that if they don't have CV on the other team, they *need* wards for vision, whereas a support with even decent CVs makes an oracle (somewhat) less valuable.

Comment: I would also add that you can use an oracle to push a lead into an even bigger advantage. If you are in a position where you can roam their jungle and clear their defensive wards, then you can control all 6 buffs on the map and force them to turtle and wait for your move. When you're ahead, use oracles to get more ahead. :)